# Access a Child Class variable

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to access the variables in a list variable of my model but cannot reach variable at the end. What is the correct method for accessing FirstName i.e

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList.FirstName)
```

Current code:

```
<div class="basket-item-delegate__input-cell">
    <h6>First Name:</h6>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList)
 </div>
```

Inside DelegatesList there is FirstName, LastName and Email. The idea the field will set the value in DelegatesList.

Snippet from Model:

```
public int EventId { get; set; }
public int CourseId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be a number")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }

public List<OrderDelegate> DelegatesList { get; set; }
```

OrderDelegate cs:

```
public class OrderDelegate
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: DelegatesList  will contain the list of OrderDelegate which contains  FirstName . you have to decide the index of the Delegate List to get the FirstName

Comment: @bommelding it's wrapped in a foreach and I've now included the variable that is looping. I have another challenge with this but its a separate issue so will make another post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DelegatesList` is a `List<OrderDelegate>` and in that case you will have to index through it like

```
Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList[i].FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.CustomerBasket.OrderLines[i].DelegatesList[j].FirstName)